# How to give name in html to get the value of this id of this attr in jquery using to use in PHP code

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

How to give name in this `<img>` to get the value of id="result" to use in php. I am using `jquery` plugin for image crop. After cropping, the preview is displaying using `<img>` with some encoded value lik this. How to give name to get the value in php.

```
<img id="result"  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABA/7">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#file").change(function(e){
            var img = e.target.files[0];

            if(!img.type.match('image.*')){
                alert("Whoops! That is not an image.");
                return;
            }

            iEdit.open(img, true, function(res){
                $("#result").attr("src", res);
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You want to make the ID `result` dynamically generated?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, what "give name" means here, or what PHP has to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a name attribute to a image but I suggest use data-name.
**http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp**

```
$(element).attr("name", "myName" );
```

or

```
$(element).attr("data-name", "myName" );
```